# Facing issue in raty function

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I am using  raty star rating in my form in rails4 and using  `gem 'nested_form'` which create multiple star rating is given as follows

```
<%= f.fields_for :round_questions do |question| %>

        <%= question.label :question %>
         <%= question.text_field :question %>
        <div class="star-questions" > </div>
               <%= question.text_field :answer %>
<% end %>

                      <%= f.link_to_add "Add a Question", :round_questions,
                                        :class=> 'btn waves-effect waves-light btn-medium custom_btn_gray', :id => "add-fields" %>
```

and the javascript is given as

```
$('.star-questions').raty({
   target     :  $("input[id^='interview_round_round_questions_attributes_'][id$=_answer]"),
    targetType : 'score',
    targetKeep : true
});
```

the browser is getting this html

```
<div class="fields">

                          <label for="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_0_question" class="">Question</label>
                              <input type="text" name="interview_round[round_questions_attributes][0][question]" id="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_0_question">

                           <div class="star-questions" style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px;"><img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="1" title="bad">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="2" title="poor">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="3" title="regular">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="4" title="good">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="5" title="gorgeous"><input type="hidden" name="score"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="interview_round[round_questions_attributes][0][answer]" id="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_0_answer">


</div><div class="fields">

                          <label for="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_1_question">Question</label>
                              <input type="text" name="interview_round[round_questions_attributes][1][question]" id="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_1_question">

                           <div class="star-questions" style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px;"><img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="1" title="bad">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="2" title="poor">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="3" title="regular">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="4" title="good">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="5" title="gorgeous"><input type="hidden" name="score"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="interview_round[round_questions_attributes][1][answer]" id="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_1_answer">


</div><div class="fields">

                          <label for="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_2_question">Question</label>
                              <input type="text" name="interview_round[round_questions_attributes][2][question]" id="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_2_question">

                           <div class="star-questions" style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px;"><img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="1" title="bad">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="2" title="poor">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="3" title="regular">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="4" title="good">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="5" title="gorgeous"><input type="hidden" name="score"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="interview_round[round_questions_attributes][2][answer]" id="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_2_answer">


</div><div class="fields">

                          <label for="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_3_question">Question</label>
                              <input type="text" name="interview_round[round_questions_attributes][3][question]" id="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_3_question">

                           <div class="star-questions" style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px;"><img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="1" title="bad">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="2" title="poor">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="3" title="regular">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="4" title="good">&nbsp;<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="5" title="gorgeous"><input type="hidden" name="score"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="interview_round[round_questions_attributes][3][answer]" id="interview_round_round_questions_attributes_3_answer">
```

I am using unique Id for this but what happen when I fill any one of the answer rating other one numbers also displays. Please guide me how to solve this.